# Drop Down Menu Hidden by div with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have this Drop Down Menu that is placed in a table row, that has some hidden content.
[image: Sample image]

I can't touch ancestror html, because I dont control it.
I have found this example https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/ but  the div still stays within the overflowing div.

There is any solution, without needing to place this drop down content in the end of the HTML with fixed position?

I'm refearing to the dropdown menu with id 'thedropdownmenu' and the div with overflow with class name 'dataTables_scrollBody'.
Please check on the jsfiddle.

[Code Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/2L8du7w6/)

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
        <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
           <table id="myDataTable" class="display no-footer DTTT_selectable dataTable" aria-describedby="myDataTable_info" role="grid" style="width: 1960px;">
              <thead>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>
                       <div id="756d44c4-21f8-4cb7-bfb2-f3e8803630c1_Ajuntar" data-requiredfields="12" class="tableAction tableActionDropdown tableActionActive" onclick="checkIfChangeWithReasonActionIsActive(this, event)">
                          <div id="thedropdownmenu" class="dropdown open">
                             <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><span id="" class="tableActionOption icon-reject" title="Ajuntar"></span></a>
                             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="tableAction" tabindex="-1" href="#" value="5a3a930462168e45246c9da7" data-option="687a2389-abfa-4915-8eec-86ea3b7f0509">Falta DNI</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="tableAction" tabindex="-1" href="#" value="5a3a930462168e45246c9da7" data-option="a5d7cd22-34bd-4cc3-9534-d19d5c31f6f0">Faltan Escrituras</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="tableAction" tabindex="-1" href="#" value="5a3a930462168e45246c9da7" data-option="23065843-eac4-4a56-964e-c22dc9755fc7">Falta SEPA</a></li>
                             </ul>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You may want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers. We have no idea what you are asking. What do you want to happen, what is happening (use your words)? what errors are you receiving?

Comment: Where do you want the drop-down to appear?

Comment: @happymacarts The drop-down is in the correct place, check the image. The problem is that one of  ancestor div have overflow set to auto which causes the dropdown to show under that div.

Comment: I might consider using the dataTables [render function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to make the row display the dropdown where I want it. That is if you have access to the DataTable init function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only see a way, using fixed positioning. It will not have the same efect, but see no other way if you don't want to change the html to other place. Example:

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can change the html of the drop-down, If that helps. 
Anyways I will try your solution, but that will require some js to set the left, top values, right?

Comment: When I say "change the html to other place", i mean move it to ancestor.